How to Sync Serialization/Deserialization of data stored in Redis for NodeJS and C# Application (ServiceStack)?
There were 2 C# Applications, Let's say Application A and Application B both were written in C# and uses ServiceStack. Both Application has a common Redis connection where the Data exchange takes place between both Applications (Using RedisClient of ServiceStack) For Example to read the data:
var customers = client.GetAll<Customer>();
Now the Application B is migrated in node JS and still the data exchange is required between both Applications. The Application B is currently using io-redis and flexible for any suggested changes to achive the functionality provided migration in the Application A is quite tough.
Is there any way the communication can be re-established between both Application by making necessary changes only in Application B (the Node JS)?
The current issue is in order to read the Data in Application A whatever is written by Application B using nodeJS and io-redis, the data need to be serialised manually like this:
var userKeys = redisClient.GetAllKeys();
var users = new List<User>();
foreach (var key in userKeys)
{
 var jsonData = redisClient.GetValue(key);
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonData))
 {
    var user = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<User>(jsonData);
    users.Add(user);
 }
}

